# Reporting without chaincode on hyperledger fabric peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Can we implement a channel between two peers and initiate a transaction just to store data without any chaincode or smartcontract? If yes any example

Comment: No you can't, you do require chaincode

Comment: so chaincode i have to install on both peers between orgA and orgB?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The only way to put/get state is via chaincode.